# Applying request headers angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm fairly new to `angular` and I'm using the latest version.

I am trying to execute a post request but I run into `CORS` issue. I believe the problem is because I don't have a content type in my request header and I want to add that to my code.

In previous version, this method below worked but not anymore.  What do I have to do to apply headers correctly in `Angular 6`?

I get the following error

> "Argument of type '{ header: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'."

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { User } from './user';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";



const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  public createUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    let getHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.http
     .post(API_URL + '/users', user, {header: getHeaders}).pipe(
        map(response => {
          return new User(response.json());
        }), catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{headers: getHeaders}` (with an `s`)?

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part

Comment: Typo in the question or in your code? Does it work without that typo?

Comment: in the question. The code still shows the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

app/json is automatically applied to HttpClient requests, so you don't need to do it.

That being said, you are using the wrong Http import.
should be:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

this.http.post(...);
```

Comment: I changed it to HttpClient and removed the headers which brings me back to the initial Cors issue. Since my POST kept getting changed to options, I thought it was because I need to specify the header.  Thanks for informing me of this feature for HttpClient. I will have to figure out another solution for the Cors issue.

Comment: To allow cors, you have to modify the server. The server is the one that allows/disallows CORS